# How do we define the density of a discrete random variable? Of a pair of mixed random variables?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n, \theta)$ and $\theta \sim \text{Unif}(0, 1)$, so that
$$P(X = k \mid \theta) = {n \choose k} \theta^k (1 - \theta)^{n - k}.$$
In order to compute the posterior, I need to write down the joint "density" of $X$ and $\theta$.

With respect to what measure does $(X, \theta)$ have a density? I guess $X$ has a density with respect to counting measure (is this accurate?) and $\theta$ with respect to lebesgue measure. What about the pair?

Comment: This mixture midweek os not correct as $\theta$ must be nonnegative.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Oops, fixed.

Comment: Take the product of the counting measure and the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @geetha290krm Does it matter that $X$ and $\theta$ are not independent here? Can I still use product measure?

Comment: For the Radon-Nikodym derivative it doesn't matter if the reference measure is a product measure. It only matters that your measure is absolutely continuous with respect to the reference measure. It's really worth investing some time into the Radon-Nikodym Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the canonical choice would be the Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to the product of the Lebesgue and the counting measure.
Working on the probability space $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with this product directly, the Radon-Nikodym derivative is $(\theta,x)\mapsto\unicode{120793}\{\theta\in[0,1],x\in\mathbb Z\}\binom{n}{x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$. The way you defined the probability measure, I would read it as the [semi-direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel#Semidirect_product), which does not require a Radon-Nikodym derivative. I'm also not entirely sure which distribution you refer to with the posterior, but if you mean the [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure), using the kernel approach above you obtain it directly as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel#Probability_Space_defined_by_Probability_Distribution_and_a_Markov_Kernel). Put, simply, it's just $\mathbb P(X=k)=\mathbb E[\binom{n}{k}Y^k(1-Y)^{n-k}]$.

Comment: That expectation is $1/(n+1)$ and $X$ has a beta-binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please recommend a textbook or reference which treats Bayesian statistics in this way using markov kernels?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I work with a combination of five or six books on probability, But most of all it's the experience from my phd. I'm also constantly looking for resources, and more often than not I can't even find the discussion of standard results. Sorry!